# Where is the DB_CONFIG file of Berkeley database located in Unix?

Tags: unix, configuration-files, berkeley-db

i'm new to Berkeley db, i have installed the version "db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz" but now i would like to find the configuration
information by using the configuration file.

I've read in the documentations that this file is named DB_CONFIG and it exists in the
database home directory.

In my system, i have uzipped the tar file under /usr/db-4.8.30.NC but i still haven't found
the DB_CONFIG file.

Well, i'm trying to find where the DB_CONFIG file is located in Unix, but i can't find it.

May you please help me?

Thanks, in advance

Comment: Voting to close, you should ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mghie: It sounds to me like programmer is trying to program an application using Berkeley DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (or a system administrator) writes the `DB_CONFIG` file by hand to modify any of the `DB_ENV` environment variables that can be over-ridden at runtime.

The `DB_CONFIG` file is stored in the `db_home` directory; the `docs/programmer_reference/env_naming.html` file has full details, but you can either pass an explicit `db_home` parameter in the `DB_ENV->open()` call or rely on the `DB_HOME` environment variable to locate the `DB_CONFIG` file, if any exists. The environment variable approach might be nice if the system administrator would reasonably want to move the storage around as they wish; the specific path name approach might be nice if you don't want to bother your system administrators with details of managing your storage.

Comment: Thanks for replying.When you say "you can either pass an explicit db_home parameter in the DB_ENV->open() call or rely on the DB_HOME environment variable to locate the DB_CONFIG file, if any exists". Where can i locate the db_home parameter (in which dir?) or how can i rely on the DB_HOME environment in order to locate the DB_CONFIG file?Shall i open a file and find these information? I'm sorry for making these questions but i'm a new user of Berkeley and i'm confused.

Comment: It really depends upon your application. You might construct the `db_env` parameter to `DB_ENV->open()` by concatenating `getenv("HOME")` with `".foo/"`. Or, if your application runs as a dedicated user, perhaps just pass `getenv("HOME")`. (Similar to squid, apache, ftpd, etc. using the home directory set for their dedicated user in `/etc/passwd`. Maybe you provide an Upstart configuration file for your users where you could set the `DB_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: Let's say that i would like to open the DB_CONFIG file. How can i open it?

Comment: `vim /path/to/my/applications/data/directory/DB_CONFIG`.

Comment: I can't understand the path. Isn't the DB_CONFIG file in the directory /usr/db-4.8.30.NC? Cause i don't know where the path you wrote me is. I'm sorry for asking these questions but i'm trying to find out how the system is organised. Also, i tried to type some commandes under the /usr/db-4.8.30.NC directory. e.g.  dbenv->repmgr_set_ack_policy(dbenv, DB_REPMGR_ACKS_ONE); and i take the output "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('". Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: `/usr/db-4.8.30.NC` is just the place where you unpacked the source code. Every application that uses Berkeley DB will have its own database, and every application has to figure out on its own where its database lives. BDB is not at all like MySQL or PostgreSQL, which run a single daemon for all interested clients -- every program that uses BDB will do all the database operations itself, in-process. And each one must figure out where its storage is available in whatever manner makes most sense for the application. What kind of application are you writing? Who runs it? How will it start?

Comment: Well i'm running an application which copies the metadata to some other servers. The app is under the dir /usr/MyFs. AS i have seen the Berkeley copies the data in the App but i would like to make some modifications in the db_config file and i can't. How can i find out where the db_config file is?

Comment: Read the application's source code to find the `DB_ENV->open()` call and find out how the application has computed the path. It could realistically do _anything_ to compute the path. If you don't have source, run `ltrace(1)` on the program to try to find the `DB_ENV->open()` call. `strace(1)` might be less noisy, but will require more careful looking.

Comment: Thanks, my system doesn't support the ltrace command "Command not found" but the strace only. Well, i used strace but it didn't say anything about DB_ENV->open() and anything about the Berkeley db.Is there any other command i can use in Unix in order to find a DB_CONFIG file?

Comment: `strace(1)` only knows system call information -- so you'll have to look for `open(2)` calls that open the database files. Try `grep 'open.*db' /tmp/strace` after running `strace -o /tmp/strace -f ...`.

Comment: Well, i executed tha command for /tmp/strace. A file containing named "strace" information is created and one of the lines contains an entry such as 17240 execve("/usr/MyFs", ["/usr/MyFs"], [/* 17 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied). Also, the grep command didn't find any word that contains the word "open".

Comment: You can't execute the program while it is being debugged? I'm very confused about that.